# Microsoft Graph API profile picture update in Java

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to work with Microsoft Graph API to update the user picture of Azure AD accounts.

I have followed this
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_update and it's seems clear for me but I'm not able to upload pictures, it fails with RessourceNotFound error message.

Below my code to retrieve the token and to upload the user picture. Retrieving the token works well.

```
private String getToken() throws Exception {
    String access_token = "";
    String url = "https://login.windows.net/TENANTID/oauth2/token";
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", "APPLICATIONID"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", "SECRET"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com"));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("PROXYADDRESS.com", 8080, "http");
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
    post.setConfig(config);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    logger.debug("Sending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    logger.debug("Post parameters : " + post.getEntity());
    logger.debug("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    String responseAsString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    try {
        access_token = responseAsString.split(",")[6].split("\"")[3]; // get the access_token from response
        logger.debug(access_token);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return access_token;
}
```

And now I try to update the user picture of one account.

```
public String updatePicture(String token) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    File file = new File("C:\\USERPICTURE.jpg");
    byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    fis.read(bytesArray);
    fis.close();
    byte[] bytesEncoded = new Base64().encode(bytesArray);

    String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USERPRINCIPALNAMEOFTHEUSER@DOMAINMAIL.COM/photo/$value";
    HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

    HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);
    request.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    request.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(bytesEncoded));

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("PROXYADDRESS.COM", 8080, "http");
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
    request.setConfig(config);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    logger.debug("Sending 'PUT' request to URL : " + url);
    logger.debug("Post parameters : " + request.getEntity());
    logger.debug("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    String responseAsString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    logger.debug(responseAsString);
    return responseAsString;
}
```

And this is the result I have..

```
2018-08-13 11:54:10,511 DEBUG (main) [IDM(getToken:391)] Sending 'POST' request to URL : https://login.windows.net/XXXXXXX/oauth2/token
2018-08-13 11:54:10,511 DEBUG (main) [IDM(getToken:392)] Post parameters : [Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded,Content-Length: 182,Chunked: false]
2018-08-13 11:54:10,511 DEBUG (main) [IDM(getToken:393)] Response Code : 200
2018-08-13 11:54:10,511 DEBUG (main) [IDM(getToken:398)] XXXXXXXXXXXX
2018-08-13 11:54:11,791 DEBUG (main) [IDM(updatePicture:448)] Sending 'PATCH' request to URL : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USERPRINCIPALNAME@XXXX.COM/photo/$value
2018-08-13 11:54:11,791 DEBUG (main) [IDM(updatePicture:449)] Post parameters : [Content-Length: 5252,Chunked: false]
2018-08-13 11:54:11,791 DEBUG (main) [IDM(updatePicture:450)] Response Code : 404
2018-08-13 11:54:11,791 DEBUG (main) [IDM(updatePicture:453)] {
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "date": "2018-08-13T09:54:11"
    }
  }
}
```

Is someone has an idea to fix that?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you base64 encode the body: `new Base64().encode(bytesArray)`. If you are sending an image, you should just send the image bytes as the body.

Comment: As for the 404, make sure the user `USERPRINCIPALNAMEOFTHEUSER@DOMAINMAIL.COM` is a member of `TENANTID`

Comment: Hello @juunas, you're right, I've removed the encode of Base64 (I've tried this because I saw on the internet someone did that..). And about the 404 you're right too. In fact the user don't have email address so it returned me 404. I have tried on my user with mailbox and the picture is fully set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do you know how to remove the picture? Didn't found in Microsoft Graph documentation

Based on my knowledge, there is **no** removing the photo rest API. From [photo Rest API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/profilephoto), we find that there is no delete photo API.

I try to delete the photo with postman. I got the method is **not allowed**.

[image]

I also check my profile with office365 site, and there is no option to delete the photo. But if you want to change the photo, you could update the photo to another one as you mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I confirm.. not possible. The only solution for now is to upload an "avatar" picture

Answer (score 1):

So, no error in my code except the base64 conversion. It fails because the user don't have a mailbox. If I choose a user with a mailbox it return a SUCCESS 200 and the picture is updated.

Now, last question, do you know how to remove the picture? Didn't found in Microsoft Graph documentation

Thanks

Comment: If you have any question, I recommand that you could update the original post or post a new SO thread to instead of adding it in an answer .